# createElement in parent vs. iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, appendchild, createelement

I have a modular Web page, each module being an iframe that can interact with the parent page. In particular the iframes add new elements to the parent (navigation, tabs, whatever). All pages are in the same domain.

So far I have always used this pattern in the iframes:

```
var newDiv=document.createElement("div");
// do stuff with newDiv
parent.document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```

It recently occurred to me that, because the newDiv is going to be attached to the parent, it would make more sense to do this:

```
var newDiv=parent.document.createElement("div");
// do stuff with newDiv
parent.document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```

My question: does it make any difference whether the new element is created with document.createElement vs. parent.document.createElement?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work ? If it does then I think (not 100% sure) both are same because `createElement` is a `DOM` method and a member of `document` object and you have access to two documents (two objects) at the same time and both contains same member functions (createElement is available in both), in this case one is in the `iframe` and another is in it's parent. So, it looks like that you are calling a method from one source instead of another source, **IMO**.

Like I said this is only an opinion so wait for more answers from the experts.